# XML really slow compared to sites using the same API (PHP, Wordpress, Supercontrol)

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, performance

I'm currently using the API from the booking engine Supercontrol in a Wordpress build here: http://ukshortbreaks.com.s191529.gridserver.com/accommodation/

It's taking such a long time to load! I can't really use caching because each search is unique.

I've tried to limit the nodes it's loading but it doesn't seem to be making any difference at all.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it sitting doing something else before it even goes looking through the XML? I'm not getting any errors, but there's maybe something weird going on.

Two other websites using the same API are super fast Mulberry Cottages and Sykes Cottages (my rep is too low to post links).

Any advice on how to speed it up would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is amateur hour!

Comment: sure how would we know? You can time using php micro time, check where the bottle neck is.

Comment: The only advice one can give is general methodology for tackling performance issues. Establish a measurement framework. Set quantified targets and compare with the measurements. Get timings for the subtasks and determine which of them is the bottleneck. Repeat, recursively. When you have found the bottleneck, remove it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay and David, both valid pieces of advice. It turns out I need to run a cron job (every time a specific node is updated) in order to store data from an external XML document in my database, then pull that data back out into the dom. Lord help me!